# Putting a AddEventListener on a button that is in InnerHTML in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html

Im am creating a page with some music, right now I am working on the 'explore' page. And you will see about 10 cards with music randomized from a array. Everything is going smoothly until right know. I added a button to start the music, but i can't seem to be able to put a AddEventListener on the button, i just made the cards with innerHTML (I know its not the best option but this project is still practice) And now I am not able to make it work on. If i put the event listener after the function with the innerHTML buttons. I am only able to get 1.

```
function handleLoadHighlights(number) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let randomSongs = Math.floor(Math.random() * songsList.length);
        let song = songsList[randomSongs];
            let background = backgroundGradients[i];

            audioFile.src = song.audio;

            highlightsOutput.innerHTML += `
            <div class="highlighted__song" style="${background.backgroundcolor} ${background.backgroundimg}">
                <div class="highlighted__description">
                    <h3 class="highlighted__description--title">${song.title}</h3>
                    <p class="highlighted__description--para">${song.artist}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="highlighted__footer">
                    <button class="highlighted__button--play"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></button>
                    <img class="highlighted__img" src="./assets/covers/${song.img}"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
            `;
    }
}
```

The function that shows me the randomized card with the song

```
const playButton = document.querySelectorAll('.highlighted__button--play');

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    playButton[i].addEventListener('click', handlePlayAudio);
}
```

My try on fixing it, just always returns the last one ofc

Comment: `handlePlayAudio` receives an event as a parameter. `event.target` will be the button that they clicked on. You can use that to find the corresponding song that should be played.

Comment: Could you give me a snippet of how you would do that?

Comment: Where is the audio in the HTML?

Comment: Yes its just in the html with a audio tag

Comment: https://music4u-liard.vercel.app/ is the link to it you might be able to seek for a solution better that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the index of the song as a data attribute of the button.

```js
function handleLoadHighlights(number) {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let randomSongs = Math.floor(Math.random() * songsList.length);
    let song = songsList[randomSongs];
    let background = backgroundGradients[i];

    audioFile.src = song.audio;

    highlightsOutput.innerHTML += `
            <div class="highlighted__song" style="${background.backgroundcolor} ${background.backgroundimg}">
                <div class="highlighted__description">
                    <h3 class="highlighted__description--title">${song.title}</h3>
                    <p class="highlighted__description--para">${song.artist}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="highlighted__footer">
                    <button class="highlighted__button--play" data-song="${randomSongs}"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></button>
                    <img class="highlighted__img" src="./assets/covers/${song.img}"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
            `;
  }
}
```

Then in `handlePlayAudio()`, you can get this index from the clicked button.

```js
let songIndex = event.target.dataset.song;
audioFile.src = songsList[songIndex].src;
```

`event` is the argument to `handlePlayAudio()`.